# Setting a new child template for a block issue in Magento 1

Tags: layout, blocks, magento-1, event-observer, template

This is my block:

```
 $_block = $event->getBlock();
 if($_block instanceof Mage_Page_Block_Html_Header){
     $_child = clone $_block;
     $_child->setType('core/template');
     $_child->setTemplate('page/html/mycustomtemplate.phtml');
     $_block->setChild('child', $_child);
 }
```

I just want to include a new template before or after the header in my observer. How can I do that ?

Comment: Which event are you observing ?

Comment: I m using this `core_block_abstract_to_html_before`.  I managed to remove or change existing blocks, but now I need to add a custom new one, which contains just a message.

Answer (score 0):

Your code definitely looks ok to me.

The problem comes from the fact that out of the box, the default `header.phtml` file looks like this:

```
<div class="header-container">
    <div class="header">
        <?php if ($this->getIsHomePage()):?>
        <h1 class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a></h1>
        <?php else:?>
        <a href="<?php echo $this->getUrl('') ?>" title="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" class="logo"><strong><?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?></strong><img src="<?php echo $this->getLogoSrc() ?>" alt="<?php echo $this->getLogoAlt() ?>" /></a>
        <?php endif?>
        <div class="quick-access">
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
            <p class="welcome-msg"><?php echo $this->getChildHtml('welcome') ?> <?php echo $this->getAdditionalHtml() ?></p>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topLinks') ?>
            <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_language') ?>
        </div>
        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topContainer'); ?>
    </div>
</div>
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topMenu') ?>
```

And, as there is no call to:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(); ?>
```

Only the following blocks are being rendered in that template:

- topSearch
- topLinks
- store_language
- topContainer
- topMenu

Two solutions here:

Either you modify this template by adding:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml(); ?>
```

Or:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('child'); ?>
```

The other solution would be to use a different block that automatically renders the child block, for example instead of the `header` block you could use the `after_body_start` container

Comment: Wouldn't it also be true that cloning the other block will give both blocks the same name, and that they have to be unique?

Comment: @tjons I'm pretty sure that, as long as the alias is unique, Magento will work it out.